# Redirect Error for website on VPS non-https and www version

Tags: ssl, redirect, vps, certbot

Hi I am a web designer and have recently starting maintaining a VPS server

I am using a Lamp VPS server running multiple PHP websites

Problem in all websites:
all "www version of websites" and some "non-https version" redirecting apache homepage (showing non-ssl with error)

Code for Virtual Hosts

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.temp.com
    ServerAlias dascc.in
    Redirect "/" "https://www.temp.com"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/temp.com/

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,END]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,END]
   </VirtualHost>
```

Code for .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

I am using Certbot for SSL certificates using

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

Also have this in website-le-ssl.conf

```
#Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
#because they have the potential to create redirection loops.
```